# Should replacing the brake pads make braking feel "softer"?

Tags: brakes

I've just had the brake pads replaced on my Skoda Fabia- apparently they'd worn very thin.

But now when I brake I have to push down much harder on the brake pedal than before. Is this to be expected?

Comment: You have to push harder at the very beg. when brand new pads because they are not bedded. Friction is lower so you need to put more pressure into the caliper to get the same deceleration. You need first to bed-in the pads. If this effect persists after 100 km, then there might be another cause.

Answer (score 2):

No. It sounds like there maybe air in the hydraulic system and it will therefore need bleeding. This could have happened for many reasons when they pushed back the pistons to replace the brake pads. I would take it back to wherever you had the brake pads changed and complain.

Comment: Just called the garage. He very confidently assured me that this is normal for new brake pads. They should settle down after the first 100 miles or so.

Comment: Then drive those 100 miles as soon as you can, THEN take it back - they're wrong, if it takes significantly more effort to stop the car now. It SHOULD NOT.