# Brake pad failure and chewed up rotor after 1 month

Tags: brake-rotor

Replaced front rotors and brake pads less than a month ago, and now my right front brake pad is completely gone....and the rotor is totally chewed up! Began to notice a metal grind like sound on the front end, just after putting 2 new tires on the front on the 9th. I first noticed the grinding sound as I pulled out of parking lot, but was in big hurry...the sound got louder and louder. Three days later I looked at my brakes and that's when I found my passenger side brake pad totally gone, and rotor chewed. Yesterday I was able to replace the rotor and brake pad, hoping it was a bad set of pads??? 
Today, my driver side brakes began making a screeching metal sound....so I replaced the pad on it. (rotor looked ok)
Does ANYONE have ideas of what could be causing this problem? Have been told bad calipers???? Bad brake pads????
***Also, while doing the brakes today I found a .5inLx.16w tiny little thing, metal, hollow cylinder like....., in with the caliper (driver side).....have no idea what it is or where it came from.
Just fyi, the only other thing I've done is replace tie rods about 2 months ago maybe????
(actually this is for my son)
Thanks for the help!!!!!!

10/22/2015 Update

Well, he got back with me and he is putting on a new CALIPER, as suggested by several wise people here, and brake pad on one side. He went with the one that made the "grinding" noise.
I will write back if this does not completely solve the problem. He was told by several people if the brake pads weren't bad when he got them, it was most likely a caliper, but he never felt the classic "pull" to one side or the other, so we were sure it was something else lol....

Comment: Did you bed the brakes properly? What is the make/model/year of the vehicle?

Comment: It is a 'Grand am SE 4cyl and I'm pretty sure he bled the brakes....done correctly??? I don't know, but I will ask tomorrow he is at work now. thank you!!

Comment: Or set them in right??? I think he did, I watched him and he looked careful making sure they fit correctly together with the hardware etc.??

Comment: Bedding occurs when you first start driving the vehicle after brake replacement. If done incorrectly it can cause excessive wear. The only other thing I can think of is if the caliper is getting stuck causing excess wear on the pads.

Comment: Oh.....I don't know the correct way to drive it, or if he did it...... and don't know how to tell if caliper is sticking, and would it be normal for both calipers to began sticking at about the same time if that were it?

Comment: Check out the link in [this answer](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/11622/4152) ... The one for Centrix. It should help you understand what bedding is. I'm leaning on the issue being a sticking caliper, though.

Comment: No, I'm sure he didn't know how to bed them....do you think he should reinstall them then bed them correctly? Sorry, had just read about bedding.

Comment: Are both pads in each caliper wearing down or is it just one?  If it is just one, is it the side of the caliper that has a piston or is it the side of the caliper without a piston?

Comment: Hi, thank you!! I'm not sure how to tell about piston. The passenger side is the first one to be completely gone and rotor chewed, in like three days of noticing a noise. Then a week at most, the driver side began a noise....was able to change pad same day noise was noticed, and found a tiny little long skinny hollow piece of metal in with the caliper about a half inch long...not sure what it was or where it came from.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely you need a new caliper.  The pistons will stick and drag slightly when they're in need of overhaul/replacement.  If any of the wheels are hot after driving, that's a very likely problem.  You may or may not smell the classic "brake smell".  If they're only sticking slightly, you won't notice the drag while driving, you'll just see the extra pad wear and you can feel the extra heat generated after higher-speed driving.

Comment: Ok, thank you!!! I will tell him to take a drive and then check for the heat....I've read he should have cleaned up all the brake dust as well, and I don't think he did that....yes, I thought it wasn't a caliper because it wasn't pulling or anything, but I see exactly what you are saying. Thank you...thank you all so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!