# Should I always replace brake pads when replacing rotors?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor

I have an issue with vibrations when driving over 80 k\h, and someone who inspected the vehicle said the rotors are warped.  Of course I realize [it could be something else](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/11632/7132) and I'm going to verify it myself, but assuming it really is the rotors, do I have to replace the brake pads at the same time, or can I just do [the pad bedding process](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/11622/7132) to shape the current pads to the new rotors?

Comment: If it was rotors you should only get vibration under braking...

Comment: @GdD  So you think maybe it's wheel weights or something like that?  I did notice when airing up the tires that the car has four different tires on it, each one from a different manufacturer with a different PSI rating...

Comment: Vibration at highway speed, when not braking, will be something to do with worn suspension components, wheel alignment, or tire/wheel balancing.  Or a combination of all of them. Unmatched tires could be an issue if the sizes are different. Are they all the same size?

Comment: Wheel balancing is a good bet, and could be the simplest to fix. In addition to @CharlieRB's list there's worn steering components and damaged wheels.

Comment: Don't read the PSI markings on the tires. Those are simply the maximum cold pressures. Look inside the driver door for the proper PSI.

Comment: Amazing what the simple things can do. Glad you found the issue.

Comment: Three of the tires are 205/60, while the front right tire is 215/60. After changing the 215 with a 205 the problem went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always recommended to replace the pads when replacing, or resurfacing, brake rotors.

The pads may look fine, but if you are trying to solve the vibration issue, using the old pads could transfer problems you cannot see, like uneven wear, cracks, etc.

Comment: Yes, always replace when new rotors...