# Car shaking when braking

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, vibration, shaking

I got a used car. I notice that on speeds higher than 80Km and when I brake, the car shakes. The shaking is very soft, it is not tough and it is not every time. I noticed it twice on a 2 hours journey on the high way. The brake pads are new, the brake disks are new, too.

Any one knows what is that? and is it dangerous?

Comment: Does the steering wheel also shake when you experience vibration?

Comment: yes. it shakes.

Comment: Your issue is most likely that the brakes were not bedded correctly. [This previous answer](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/11245/4152) should describe the issue.

Comment: I do not have problems in braking distance. The problem was described in the original post: shaking when braking.

Comment: Which is due to not being bedded correctly. Please read my answer I posted there. Specifically read the two links provided. They will tell you all you need to know about bedding and why it needs to be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common issue that makes a car shake when breaking is warped rotors. With warped rotors when you break the pad and caliper slide side to side causing the vibration. Depending on how badly they are warped the vibration may only be felt at high speed but the worse they are the lower the speed the vibration will be felt at.

The best solution is to have the rotors turned using an on car lathe (if the rotors are not worn out). The next best is to have them turned off the car. The third best is to replace them. All of these solutions also depend on the state of the pads. If the pads are more than 50% worn and are all grooved then just wait till they wear out to fix the vibration. If the pads are almost brand new and not grooved then turn the rotors.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, is it dangerous to drive with this problem? i noticed that the shaking happens only when braking with speed between 75-90 Km/H.

Comment: @M.M Assuming nothing else is wrong then it's not super unsafe. If the pulsation is severe enough there is a condition that the calipers float and braking ability is degraded.