# When I press the brake and my car is shaking

Tags: brakes

When I press the brake pedal, my car is shakes. However, it is fine when I drive it. Does anyone know what's going on with my car and how should I fix it? If I ask someone to fix it, how much would it cost and how long would it take approximately?

Comment: Especially, when the car is not moving.

Comment: What model of car is it? Am I reading this properly, your car is shaking when you press the brake, especially when the car is not moving???

Comment: Does the rpm drop when your car is shaking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Car shaking when braking](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21493/car-shaking-when-braking)

Comment: I don't think it's a dup, notice that this happens when the car is **not** moving. I suspect a vacuum leak.

Comment: Now I am kind convinced that it is a vacuum leak. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your rotors are warped pretty bad on the front honestly. Sounds like you need brakes and rotors, might as well do the whole car. Rotors are easily warped nowdays due to quality, usage, and even by hitting a puddle of water after or during braking because it shifts the rotors temperature so quickly from hot to cold that the steel warps. Hence the shaking when braking.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will go to auto repair shop on this Satursday!

Comment: No problem, just make sure not to replace those worn out components with really cheap ones or you'll be in the same predicament within a matter of months most likely. If you could inform me of what auto parts stores are in your area I will gladly explain the difference between all the brands and versions they'll have for your car and can recommend some if you'd like and take those parts to a shop to be installed and you'll have the comfort of knowing exactly what quality of braking parts you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If the car shakes when you apply the brakes while it is moving, then the problem is likely with the rotors. However since it happens when the car is **not** moving, then I'd suspect a vacuum leak.

Listen carefully around the brake booster (the large round object more or less in front of the driver in the engine compartment), I suspect that there is a leak that is causing the idle mixture to change, probably too lean as air is being pulled in when the brake is applied. That cause the engine to stumble.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right to me. Since it says serving engine soon.

Answer (score 0):

This would be your rotors needing replacement, try braking hard from 50 km/h but not to the extent of hearing the tires squeal or reaching a complete stop, if you feel some vibration in the driving wheel then the rotors are pretty bad, if not, try the same thing from 100 km/h; if you feel vibration, the damage is somehow less but still needs changing.
I've changed mine along with the brake pads and now there's no vibration at all.